# Wordpress database connection

Tags: database

My site was hacked and I have loaded everything back up but the pages, posts, images etc are not showing on the site. I have noticed in my database ameqt_wp507 it has a list saying wp_507posts etc and another that says wp6t_posts etc. The one with wp6t has all the content in it. How do I make it look at that info?

Thanks
Sarah

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your wp-config.php file and look for the table prefix. That should be wp6t_.